# Adding two Number

Tags: php, string, substring, decimal, type-conversion

I want to sum (ADD) two number like

```
$numberOne = 50.400;  //50 is KG and 400 is grams i-e 50 KG and 400 g
$numberTwo = 50.400;
$sum = $numberOne + $numberTwo; //100.8
```

I need result i-e `$sum = 100.800` // it means 100 kg and 800 grams.

Actullay i am calculating KG and Grams. why i am doing this because i am calculating total price from kg and grams. I am saving this in DB too the datatype is decimal

Correct me I am doing something wrong.

Comment: So have you actually tried looking at the value of $sum after doing this addition? What is the actual problem?

Comment: You are getting the result in kilograms... 1000 grams is 1 kilogram... You can't have 1 result containing two units of measurement

Comment: if user input 50 it means 50 kg but if user input 50.400 it means 50 kg and 400 grams i am treating it like this. what i am doing wrong in it ??

Comment: actually i am getting (50.400) from customer scale.

Comment: @moazamali You could use a better example for the input to make your question more clear. '50.4' and '50.40' would show the difference to decimal numbers. You should also quote the number string, because they are not decimals.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a number as string with 3 decimals use

```
$number_as_string = number_format($sum, 3, '.', '');
```

To convert a string input, where the kilograms and grams are separated by '.', you can use the following function (input is not a decimal number!):

```
function str2decimal($numberStr)
{
    list($kg, $g) = explode('.', $numberStr);
    $numberDecimal = $kg + ($g / 1000);
    return $numberDecimal;
}
```

Example:

```
$number1Decimal = str2decimal('50.4');      // 50.004 kg    =  50 kg +  4 g
$number2Decimal = str2decimal('50.40');     // 50.04 kg     =  50 kg + 40 g
$sum = $number1Decimal + $number2Decimal;   // 100.044 kg   = 100 kg + 44 g
```

Comment: sometime the user just enter 50 which means just 50 kg. sometime user input 50.4 which means 50 kg and 4 grams and sometime user input 50.400 which is 50 kg and 400 grams

Comment: @moazamali Ah. Input is NOT a decimal. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use round() function. You can set the number of decimals you wish and the method (round up / down):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function

Update: You need to convert the user input into a consistent format using a function before calculating the sum.

```
function formatWeightInput($number) {
    $numberParts = explode('.', $number);
    $number = $numberParts[0] . '.' . str_pad($numberParts[1], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);    
    return $number;
}

$numberOne = formatWeightInput('50.4');
$numberTwo = formatWeightInput('50.400');

$sum = number_format($numberOne + $numberTwo, 3); //100.404
```

Comment: when user input 50.4 it means 50 kg and 4 grams